# List of Permutations in Racket without using Functions like map and lambda

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, permutation

I am not able to write a helper function which does the same job as map and lambda

```lisp
(define (permutations lst)                                                               
       (cond [(empty? lst) '()]                                                               
       [(empty? (rest lst)) (list lst)]                                                         
       [else???]))
```

Comment: I take it you also can't use `permutations` or `in-permutations`?

Comment: Yes, That's true

Comment: I can use only Lower order functions like (append, cons, first, rest, reverse and few others). I cant use (lambda, map, for, permutations)

Comment: see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164928/849891) (by me) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one approach to doing this.  I assume you *are* allowed to write helper functions.

The first step is to realise that at some point you are going to need to take a list of elements and 'thread' something through it, producing all the possible new lists with that element inserted somewhere.  So given `(1 2)` and `3` you want to make `((3 1 2) (1 3 2) (1 2 3))`.

And for reasons which will become clear I'm going to do this in such a way that the function *adds* its answers to some preexisting ones.  And it's going to have, itself, a little helper function.

```
(define (thread-list e l into)
  ;; Thread e through l accumulating into into
  (thread-list-loop e '() l into))

(define (thread-list-loop e before after into)
  ;; Do the work of threading e through a list:
  ;; - before is the chunk of list before e;
  ;; - after is the chunk after e;
  ;; - into is what we're collecting into
  (if (null? after)
      ;; We now just need before with e at the end
      (cons (append before (list e)) into)
      ;; add the current thing to results and loop
      (thread-list-loop
       e
       (append before (list (first after)))
       (rest after)
       (cons (append before (list e) after) into))))
```

So let's test this:

```
> (thread-list 1 '(2 3) '())
'((2 3 1) (2 1 3) (1 2 3))
```

Now we want a function which will take an element, and a bunch of lists, and thread the element through each of the lists, accumulating the result:

```
(define (thread-lists e lists into)
  ;; thread e through each element of lists, accumulating into into
  (if (null? lists)
      into
      (thread-lists
       e
       (rest lists)
       (thread-list e (first lists) into))))
```

And checking this:

```
> (thread-lists 1 '((2 3) (3 2)) '())
'((3 2 1) (3 1 2) (1 3 2) (2 3 1) (2 1 3) (1 2 3))
```

And I'm going to stop here, but *look at what the above call did*: given `((2 3) (3 2))`, which is the permutations of `(2 3)`, and `1`, it returned the permutations of `(1 2 3)`!  So you should now be able to write another function, `permutations`, which makes use of `thread-lists` to create permutations.

---

Note I don't know if this approach is anything like efficient and I would expect it not to be.  It is, I think, fairly clear.

Comment: It works for elements upto 3. Do you have a tip for elements above 3?

Comment: Given a list `(e . x)` then if you have the permutations of `x`, say `px`, `(thread-lists e px '())` is the permutations of `(e . x)`.

Comment: Ah, Okay. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`map` is just an abstractiom. Imagine you make a typical list eater:

```
;; add 2 to each element
(define (add2 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (+ 2 (car lst))
            (add2 (cdr lst)))))

(add2 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (3 4 5)

;; reverse each sublist in a list
(define (revel lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (reverse (car lst))
            (revel (cdr lst)))))

(revel '((1 2) (3 4))) ; ==> ((2 1) (4 3))
```

Do you notice how similar those two are? It's almost 90% the same code. The common code is the core of `map`:

```
(define (map1 f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (f (car lst))
            (map1 f (cdr lst)))))
```

Ad now we can implement the two using `map1`

```
(define (add2 lst)
  (map1 (lambda (v) (+ v 2)) lst))

(define (revel lst)
  (map1 reverse lst))
```

Of course `map` is more than `map1` since it also supports more list arguments, but implementing a full `map` is beyond the scope of this post.